# angular firebase hosting unsuccessful

Tags: angular, firebase, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

I am following [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-progressive-web-apps-with-angular) to build angular progressive web app.

I created project on firebase and successfully deployed it.

```
You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  /Users/nitish/development/ng-pwa

Before we get started, keep in mind:

  * You are initializing in an existing Firebase project directory

? Which Firebase CLI features do you want to setup for this folder? Press Space to select featu
res, then Enter to confirm your choices. Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites

=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, 
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

i  .firebaserc already has a default project, skipping

=== Hosting Setup

Your public directory is the folder (relative to your project directory) that
will contain Hosting assets to be uploaded with firebase deploy. If you
have a build process for your assets, use your build's output directory.

? What do you want to use as your public directory? dist
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
? File dist/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of dist/index.html

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

✔  Firebase initialization complete!
shannon:ng-pwa nitish$ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'ng-pwa-6b066'...

i  deploying hosting
i  hosting: preparing dist directory for upload...
✔  hosting: 10 files uploaded successfully

✔  Deploy complete!
```

hosting:

```
shannon:ng-pwa nitish$ firebase open hosting:site
Opening Hosting: Deployed Site link in your default browser:
https://ng-pwa-6b066.firebaseapp.com
shannon:ng-pwa nitish$
```

However in my browser all I see is:

[image]

My project structure with dist folder:

[image]

Why this is happening?

Comment: Is it working now? Sometimes it just takes some time.

Comment: No it's still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That guide is for Angular 5 and how Angular apps get built changed in Angular 6.

When running `firebase init` one of the answers needs to change. The public directory is now app specific instead of just `dist`.

> What do you want to use as your public directory? dist/ng-pwa

For an existing app you can change `firebase.json` from:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    ...
  }
}
```

To:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/ng-pwa",
    ...
  }
}
```

This is because Angular is making it easier to build multiple apps with the CLI so they need their own folder within `dist`. [pwa.ng](https://pwa.ng/) is a more current guide if you want specific steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and explanation! It did solve the issue

Comment: Yep. You can read a little about it in the [v6 release notes](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v6.0.0).